# What event fires when bound controls are refreshed?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, controls, refresh, databound

Can you tell me what event fires when individual textboxes that are bound to a data source using the properties pane gets refreshed?

I wish to use this event to populate a few textboxes that are not bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what property control is bound, usually textboxes are bound on Text property, so your "event" is `TextChanged` event